# Ionic app global AppCtrl, is this right?

Tags: angularjs, security, ionic-framework, best-fit

This is the third time this week that I reach some one code that user an AppController like this in it app

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div id="inner" ng-view=""  ></div>
</body>
```

And in the controller they redirect to the different parts of the app,
like this

```
.controller("AppController",function({$location}{
    if(isUserAthenticated){
        $location.path("/home");
    }else{
       $location.path("/login")
    }
});
```

Is this the correct way to do this. Because it doesn't seem to me. I see this approach very hacky and there should be a right way to do it.
Can you guys let me know the best and recommended way to handle this kind of scenarios?

**UPDATE: Routing config**

```
   // delete  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Access-Control-Request-Headers"];
    $routeProvider
        .when('/app', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
        }).
    when('/privados', {
        templateUrl: 'views/privados.html',
        controller: 'PrivadosCtrl  as ctrl'
    }).
    when('/mensaje/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'views/mensaje.html',
        controller: 'MensajeCtrl as ctrl'
    }).
    when('/grupales', {
        templateUrl: 'views/grupales.html',
        controller: 'GrupalesCtrl as ctrl'
    }).
    when('/comunicados', {
        templateUrl: 'views/comunicados.html',
        controller: 'ComunicadosCtrl as ctrl'
    }).
    when('/contactos', {
        templateUrl: 'views/contactos.html',
        controller: 'ContactosCtrl'
    }).
    when('/perfil', {
        templateUrl: 'views/perfil.html',
        controller: 'PerfilCtrl'
    }).
    when('/principal', {
        templateUrl: 'views/principal.html',
        controller: 'PrincipalCtrl as ctrl'
    }).
    when('/nmensaje/:type', {
        templateUrl: 'views/nmensaje.html',
        controller: 'NMensajeCtrl as ctrl'
    }).
    when("/user/password",{
        templateUrl:"views/passwordreset.html",
        controller: "ResetPasswordCtrl as ctrl"
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/app'
    });
```

Comment: Could you please share your routes config, so I can put all together in a answer.

Comment: This code is not mine, it is legacy code that some one give to me. But anyway i am sharing the routes config

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I found to manage the Authentication in an Angular App is the following:

Inside the `.config()` method of your Angular App:

```
//this event will be fired in every location change.
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(e, toState, fromState) {
            if (toState.loginRequired) {
                if (!isUserAthenticated()) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            }
        });
```

then in your routes you could specify which one required the login:

```
when('/nmensaje/:type', {
    templateUrl: 'views/nmensaje.html',
    controller: 'NMensajeCtrl as ctrl',        
    loginRequired: true
}).
when("/user/password",{
    templateUrl:"views/passwordreset.html",
    controller: "ResetPasswordCtrl as ctrl",
    loginRequired: true

}).
```

Furthermore you can create an Angular Factory to manage the authentication status of the user.

Note that with this approach you wont need an AppCtrl.